# (Java 1.14) Can I use tildes in command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to run a block command like

```
/fill ~ ~ ~ ~15 ~15 ~15 minecraft:gravel 1 replace minecraft:air
```

and it's not filling anything. Do they accept tildes?

Edit: tileData and replaceDataValue only exist in Bedrock, so that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: Whenever something doesn't work in a command block, try it in chat. Then you'll see that the `1` does nothing except producing a syntax error. The output of the command block should also tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing too many arguments to the command. [/fill takes a maximum of 9](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/fill), but you entered 10. Remove the 8th argument and then it should work. (Also note that the last argument is able to accept NBT tag arguments, but should also work with normal material types.)

And yes, /fill does accept tildes.

Comment: `minecraft:air` should be valid with `replaceTileName`, which is an argument that becomes available when using `replace`, but other than that this is right, the extra `1` in the middle there is messing this up in the java edition